# Using iptables to restrict access to ssh by IP

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, iptables

I would like to allow a certain IP addresses or a whole network (source) to reach my servers with ssh connection
and to drop all other unauthorized source IP addresses.

Comment: Have a look at [Secure SSH Access](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/87/Keeping_SSH_access_secure) you can also limit access directly within the ssh daemon

Answer (score 7):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED --source x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

access only from x.x.x.x

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

drop all other packets to port 22

Comment: Hopefully the default rule is REJECT in which case you wouldn't have to define the second rule.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that the OUPUT chain is unrestricted. First question is what security does filtering by state add to the first rule if you include all of the states except INVALID? Couldn't you remove RELATED from the rule? Second question is doesn't filtering by state on the second rule miss packets with state INVALID? Why not just drop the state filtering entirely on the second rule?

Answer (score 4):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 12.34.56.78/16 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT
```

There are other ways to do it, but this is simplest when we know nothing about your other rules.

Comment: Why the /16? Is it for dynamic ip from isp? Would not need for static ip I assume?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes command line IpTables syntax can be a bit much to learn/digest.  If you're new(ish) to linux administration; you might consider installing something like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/).  You can use their gui to create your rules, and then go back and check the "/etc/sysconfig/iptables" file and see the actual syntax.

I would then recommend using Webmin & IpTables to lock down webin access to only those specific IP addresses you wish. You use the same syntax as some of the other posters have answered, just changing the PORT to whatever you setup Webmin to use. (Hopefully something OTHER than the standard port:10000).

Comment: I'd like to understand why someone would vote this down?  Is this considered unhelpful? Poorly written?  I'd genuinely appreciate the constructive criticism.

Comment: Hi, I was not the one who voted you down but I think the idea on this post was to harden the Server security. Some may believe that adding "webmin" is actually weakening the security since you are introducing yet another attack-able surface: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-358/Webmin.html